# ImportXML Googlesheetsby ID

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, import, google-sheets-formula, zillow

Greetings I am looking to import information from a page on zillow

URL: https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/2088542183_zpid/40.684299,-74.220779,40.652106,-74.25009_rect/14_zm/

the URL is located in cell A2

I'm using the importXML function and have the following syntax

```
=importxml($A2, "//*[@id='yui_3_18_1_1_1539958615120_11585']")
```

unfortunately the content is coming up as empty! Any help?

Comment: I checked that site and as far as I see, the `yui` numbers change on every refresh of the page, so you will never be able the scrape the page using that number. You can see this using your browser developer tools.

Comment: What data are you looking for? Maybe search on a different criteria? Also note that many sites load data into `iframes` than don't exist at the point when `importXML` is activated. In some case you can track the AJAX requests and get the data loaded later but its more difficult.

Comment: Have you considered using the Zillow API? Does it include the data that you're interested in?

Comment: The URL is not working.